# What's the closest thing out there like CPAN, but for Groovy?

Tags: groovy, repository, cpan

I am about to plunge into Groovy and Grails and am looking for the main places Groovy users share code.  Any tips?

Comment: Thanks for reigning me in, @rockinthesixstring.  :-)  Was torn about selecting my accepted answer, FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Cookbook+Examples
http://www.groovyexamples.org/
http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not groovy or grails specific, one of the main ways Java libraries are shared is through Maven.  Since groovy and grails are built on the Java platform, Maven is widely used there too.  Maven itself is a project for managing the dependencies of large projects and they provide a method of automatically resolving and downloading jar files from remote repositories.  While it's mostly used to download binaries, it can download source and javadoc, too.

A good starting point is Maven Central, which hosts a large number of widely used java projects.  Maven's not great for discovering what's out there, but it's great once you know what you want.  There's a search interface here: http://search.maven.org/

To use a jar from maven in your groovy project, use the [`@Grab` annotation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape).

In grails, you can declare maven dependencies in your [`BuildConfig.groovy`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.7.2%20Dependency%20Repositories).

Comment: That is fantastic to know!  (I am also relatively new to Java.)  Maven is one of those things I've heard mentioned all over the place, but never knew its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's one central place in the Groovy world that you can look up shared code. The closest thing to CPAN would be the [Grails plugin repository](http://www.grails.org/plugins/) but that's only limited to Grails-specific extensions.